# Showing the state of variables when jest finds an error

Tags: jestjs

I'm doing a tutorial on jest ([link](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started)) and I wrote a sum function and tested it.

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

Is it possible to show the state of variables when jest finds an error?

To give you an example
Now you get this but not the state of variables:

[image]
But I would like to see:

```
error when:
i=0 or j=0
```

Answer (score 1):

When testing result of given function, it's better to run multiple tests with one `expect` instead of one test with multiple checks. To do so, I would recommend you checking out [jest-each](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-each) library. Then you can run multiple tests with one `expect`. `jest-each` gives you also possibility to insert tested arguments in the name of the test, so to wrapping this up, with `jest-each` you could write something like that:

```js
each`
    a    | b    | expected
    ${1} | ${1} | ${2}
    ${6} | ${9} | ${15}
    ${4} | ${2} | ${6}
    `
.it('adding $a to $b should give $expected', ({ a, b, expected }) => {
    expect(sum(a, b)).toBe(expected)
})
```

I'm not sure but I guess if you go deep down in documentation you will find also a way to generate dynamically arguments to pass it to test.

Comment: Supernice to know. I think you could generate the each input by a function createData() that you could test large amounts of variables, thanks!